# Error:build failed Expo.Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 450

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Not using any separate Android folder. Running **eas build -p android --profile preview** to generate apk file in expo site. I have tried all possibility but no luck.

Uninstall node and package-lock.json --- No use
Installed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvIw0.png)

Trying to generate apk file.